# OSX Yosemite - can't login anymore

Tags: macos

since i rebooted my MacBook Pro today i cannot login anymore on the latest Yosemite. When i type in my password the loading bar appears and moves. After 25% the screen gets darker and the bar freezes.

I tried everything i know

- Using guest account (this worked)
- Ising my second user (same problem)
- Repairing volume with the OSX Utilities
- Using the terminal to do puswitch
- cmd-option-P-R
- I cant reinstall Yosemite because i haven't got 10GB free space

I'm really frustrated now. What can i do to prevent loosing my data?

regards,
m

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User: http://superuser.com

Comment: Not really a question for SO, try asking at [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem using Mac OS X. You may be able to get help on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it resolved when I went into USERS in system preferences and monkeyed around:

1. set up another user as administrator using my old password
2. shut off automatic login to my account
3. changed my login password
4. selected "start new password keychain" when prompted to either do that or log in with the old one.

Not an expert! This simply did the trick. 
 on on '07 iMac that hasn't liked Yosemite.